# How can I create a two-column layout in GitHub Wiki (One column for an image, the other for text)?

Tags: html, github, markdown, wiki, readme

I'm preparing a wiki, and it would be of great convenience for me to be able to format my content in two columns: one column containing an image, and the other column containing descriptive text.
Given how sanitized GitHub's CSS is, I'm struggling to find a way to do this other than by creating a two-columned table. This tabular approach isn't ideal because the table borders are an eye sore, and there's seemingly no way to hide the borders (min. border thickness is 1pt.).

I can centre images as follows:

```
<p> align="left">
<img src="https://github.com/rerendered/gdd/blob/a4bfd168f9716db64e20a478ec7f185c70cd992c/1.gif" />
```

But I don't know if there's a way for me to add text on either side of the image, instead of immediately below it.

Similarly, I can have two images side by side using the following, but I would need to replace one of the images with text that begins from the top of the adjacent image:

```
<p align="center"> 
<img alt="Light" src="https://github.com/test/gdd/blob/a4bfdd168f9716db64e20a478ec7f185c70cd992c/1.gif" width="45%">
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<img alt="Dark"
src="https://github.com/test/gdd/blob/a4bfdd168f9716db64e20a478ec7f185c70cd992c/1.gif" width="45%">
</p>
```

I'm quite new to all of this, including CSS, so if anyone has any advice for me, I'd really appreciate it.
A mock up of what I would like to achieve is as follows:

[mock-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUyIA.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please put your codes in the question not as an image. That's more readable.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no way to do this with GitHub's markdown, since its CSS will always override your styling.